# Maid RPG Scenario?

Tags: adventure-writing, maid

I'm having trouble coming up with a scenario for my friends and me to play using the [Maid RPG](http://www.MaidRPG.com/) book. I've looked over the character creation and random events, and have looked at some of the examples they have given.

Are there any step by step instructions for creating a scenario using this RPG? Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 9):

You can get away without using a prepared scenario in Maid RPG, at least at first. Have the Master give some arbitrary orders, roll on the random events chart, and watch the players scramble for Favor points in the resulting chaos.

To make a scenario, you essentially want three things:

1. A problem or situation that can't be resolved in a single encounter
2. A planned series of encounters, events or tasks for the situation, in which the player characters will have to compete and/or work together to earn the Master's favour
3. Some sort of new custom game mechanic for the scenario, to keep things interesting

You can draw scenario ideas from anime or other fiction or non-fiction sources. *Hayate the Combat Butler* is good inspiration for Maid RPG: it's an extremely wacky anime about a spoiled rich girl and her staff of butlers and maids. Pretty much anything can inspire a Maid RPG scenario, considering that one of the random encounters is "mansion blasts into space and the setting changes to sci-fi."

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine ran Maid using the anime/manga [Black Butler (Kuroshitsuji)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Butler) as inspiration.  The basic summary of the game was that a multitude of demonic guests were showing up at the manor with various outlandish and conflicting requests, and the PCs had to deal with it all.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the show is on Netflix instant watch.  I've never watched it, but it shows up in my recommendations all the time.

Comment: I watched an episode of Black Butler, and I think that it is a good way to get an idea.  Does your friend have any specific episode they watched?

Comment: I don't think it was based on a particular episode.